# How to calculate the mean of a pandas DataFrame with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, mean

I have a DataFrame that looks like as follows (the address key is the index):

`address    date1    date2    date3    date4    date5   date6    date7
<email>      NaN      NaN      NaN       1       NaN     NaN      NaN`

I want to calculate the mean across a row, but when I use `DataFrame.mean(axis=1)`, I get `NaN` (in the above example, I want a mean of 1). I get `NaN` even when I use `DataFrame.mean(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)`. How can I get the correct mean for the rows in this DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite appearances your dtypes are not numeric hence the `NaN` values, you need to cast the type using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype):

```
df['date4'] = df['date4'].astype(int)
```

then it will work, depending on how you loaded/created this data then it should be something that you should correct at that stage rather than as a post-processing step if possible

You can confirm what the dtypes are but looking at the output from `df.info()` and also you can filter non-numeric columns out using `select_dtypes`: `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])` to select just the numeric columns